# Calculating model fields

Tags: django

Hi I have the following models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)


    def maths_cal_1(self):
        if self.student_model.filter(test__test_name__iexact="maths"):
            return self.student_model.s1- self.student_model.start


class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    test_out_of = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    CHOICE = ( 
        (u'ENG', u'English'), 
        (u'MTS', u'Maths'),
        )
    KLA = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICE)


class Display(models.Model):
    full_name = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student_model')  
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    start = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    s1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

What I can't workout is how to calculate on the fly simple maths operations based on figures entered in start and s1 fields in the Display model.
I have attempted this with the ‘maths_cal_1’ method but when I try to render the results in the template I either get errors or blanks depending on which model I place the method in.
The problem is I believe, that each student object has many tests. I can't seem to correctly do the calculation of the desired test and return the results. In this case I want to return the calculation s1-start fields for the maths Test object for each student.
How can I do theses calculations for each individual test model for each student on the fly?
Thanks.

update: the working code:

```
    def maths_cal_1(self):
    cal_list = []

    for tname in ['Maths']:
        try:
            maths_test = self.student_model.get(test__test_name__iexact=tname)
            result = int(maths_test.s1) - int(maths_test.start)

            if result:
                cal_list.append(result)
            else:
                cal_list.append("")
        except (Display.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            cal_list.append("")

    return cal_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you actually need to get the result of the filter rather than just checking for its existence.

```
try:
    maths_test = self.student_model.get(test__test_name__iexact="maths")
    result = maths_test.s1 - maths_test.start
except Display.DoesNotExist:
    result = None

return result
```

(Note that there's a further problem, given that `s1` and `start` are both char fields: subtracting one from the other won't give you anything useful. Not sure what you are really intending to do here. you might need to cast it to desired types. Can you provide sample data and desired outcome?)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, with some adjustments I got your code to work (I have edited my question with the final code for the benefit of others). The reason why those fields are CharFields is because not every test result is in the form of a int. Some are grade based (A, B) etc.